# access browserify -r params in karma

Tags: karma-runner, browserify

I call browserify with npm from the package.json scripts block. Here's an abbreviated version of the script.

```
"build:js": "browserify -r ./config.js:config -e -d src/index.js > build/index.js"
```

Everything works great. Inside index.js, I just refer to this parameter using: `require('config')` and browserify does the rest.

Now I'm trying to set up karma with browserify for testing, and karma-browserify can't find that variable. I've looked around and haven't found much, but tried to add `require: ['./src/app/config/config-dev.js']` to my `karma.conf.js` inside the browserify object, like so:

```
browserify: {
    debug: true,
    require: ['./src/app/config/config-dev.js']
}
```

But karma doesn't make the connection between the require statement in the index to the parameter file, if nothing else, then because it isn't named. What I need to know is the syntax for karma when I use browserify CLI to add a param.

Any pointers to documentation explaining this or ideas about what I could try here would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by shortening the `require` for `config.js`? Is it so that you get a different config based on the environment or something else?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What am I shortening? I abbreviated the script command to remove the parts that don't pertain to the question. Is that what you mean? @casr

Comment: My guess was that you wanted to include a different config for your production and testing environments?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to pass environment specific variables to the build script.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your require resolution to your `package.json` under the [`"browser"` field](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field).

E.g.:

```
"browser": {
  "config": "./config"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: `browserify` was always intended to take server-side commonjs-style modules to the browser. Not all modules can work in the browser so you have the `"browser"` key to set up overrides. In this case, whenever `require("config")` is found by `browserify` then it replaces that with `require("./config")`.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your recommendation. The build assembles everything correctly for the browser. I'm trying to figure out how to pass the same config object to karma-browserify.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to have a different config based on your environment then you could do:

`./config.js`:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = { /* production config */ };
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  module.exports = { /* development config */ };
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  module.exports = { /* test config */ };
}
```

then in your `package.json` you would have something like:

```
"scripts": {
   "build:js": "NODE_ENV=production browserify -d -e src/index.js",
   "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "envify"
  ]
}
```

[`envify`](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) being a crucial part which allows you to replace environment variables with their string directly in the code. e.g.: `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` might become simply `'development' === 'development'`. Such things can then be removed with a minification tool like [`uglifyjs`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

Comment: I already have a different build based on environment using a browserify script. I'm trying to pass an environment parameter to karma-browserify.